# Castle Windsor and WPF Navigation

Tags: wpf, castle-windsor

I have a WPF application in which I already use Castle Windsor typed factories to create the Views and ViewModels. The Application itself has a sdi interface and uses the built in WPF Page and Frame components for navigation.

As I want to release all the view models used on a page upon navigation, I tried to use a scoped lifestyle to accomplish this. The basic idea is to dispose the current scope and create a new one before a new page is shown.

My problem now is that the is a null reference exception in the castle scope implementation randomly. Sometimes the code runs through without problems, and sometimes it won't work.

The exception occurs in 
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.CallContextLifetimeScope.GetCachedInstance(ComponentModel instance, ScopedInstanceActivationCallback createInstance) in Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Lifestyle\Scoped\CallContextLifetimeScope.cs:Line 81.

Do you basically think this is a good approach or are there any better solutions?
If you say it's ok to do it this way, do you have any ideas about the exception?

Thanks
Markus